# GestureRecognizer above 2 number isn't working

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have 2 labels and uiimage with user interaction enabled and added a recognizer by this code:

```
let tapOnImagesOrLabels = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(login.logInTapped(_:)))

/* Line 1 */ test2.addGestureRecognizer(tapOnImagesOrLabels)

/* Line 2 */ test.addGestureRecognizer(tapOnImagesOrLabels)

/* Line 3 */ registerBtnLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapOnImagesOrLabels)

test2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

test.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

registerBtnLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
//...


@IBAction func logInTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    print("clicked")
}
```

I'm getting the print output only when last recognizer is added for example I'm getting output clicked in this case when I'm clicking 'RegisterBtnLabel' but when I changed the Line 2 with 3 for example the code working when I'm clicking 'test'

Comment: You are correct. You can only add a single tap recognizer to a single view. If you need to handle common gestures among the views, point all the gesture to the same selector.

Comment: Remember, variable and function names start with a lowercase letter not an uppercase letter.

Comment: @dfd how can I do that?

Comment: Using your code, change **tapOnImageOrLabels** to, say **tapRecognizer1**. Then copy that line twice and make a **tap2** and **tap3**. Now you have three recognizers pointed to the same selector or function. All you need to do at that point is add **tap1** to **test**, **tap2** to **test2**, and **tap3** to **registerButtonLabels**.

Answer (score 0):

I handle it by adding more taprecognizer ( for each one )